# Configuring SQLCipher on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: linux, openssl, configure, sqlcipher, ubuntu-14.10

i have a problem in configuring SQLCipher:
in dynamic linking
`./configure --enable-tempstore=yes CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC" LDFLAGS="-lcrypto"`
i receive this error:
        checking whether the C compiler works... no
and in static linking
`./configure --enable-tempstore=yes CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC" LDFLAGS="/usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a"`
this error:
        configure: error: Library crypto not found. Install openssl!"

for static method, i built last version of openssl

what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem solved!
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install sqlcipher`
thanks to Diego

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, in Ubuntu 14.04.02... Openssl was already installed but I was missing some header files. Try with

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

and then

```
./configure --enable-tempstore=yes CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC" LDFLAGS="-lcrypto"
```

that worked for me.

Comment: tnx  
this time i got "E: Unable to locate package libssl-dev"

Comment: Wouldn’t installing the ubuntu package of sqlcipher fit for you? Didn’t tell before because may be you are looking for an specific version... if not: "sudo apt-get install sqlcipher"

Comment: Worked for me. Thank You Diego ;)
i was in dead end!